# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, react-redux

So, when I am trying to access my news props to display news title to my page I am receiving and error like this one:

[Error Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhpgW.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Search from './Search';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import NewsItem from './NewsItem';

class NewsResults extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Search />
                {this.props.news.map(item => {
                    return <NewsItem new={item} key={item.objectID} showButton={true}/>
                })
            }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state)
    return {
        news: state.news
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(NewsResults);
```

NewsItem.js is just a component through which I will display the results on my application.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class NewsItem extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
          <div className="col-sm-12 col-sm-3">
            <div className="thumbnail">
              <div className="caption">
                <h3>{this.props.new.title}</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NewsItem;
```

This is where I'm fetching my information from an api and then I want to display on my page using maps

```js
class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        query: ''
      };
    }

    search(){
        console.log('Search button clicked', this.state.query);
        let url = `http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=${this.state.query}`;
        // console.log(url);
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(response=> response.json())
        .then(jsonObject => {this.props.news(jsonObject.results)});
    }
```

This is my redux action code in action.js file

```
export const NEWS = "NEWS";

export function news(items) {
    const action = {
        type: NEWS,
        items
    }
    return action;
}
```

This is the reducer file

```js
import { NEWS } from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    news: []
}

export default function (state= initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case NEWS:
            console.log("News are ",action.items);
            return {
                ...state,
                news: action.items
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

So now I have changed my reducer to be in 2 seperate files I will post below. Also by doing that error message changed to this:

[This is the new Error I am getting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKefi.png)

My reducer files are below:

```js
import { NEWS } from '../actions';

export default function news(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case NEWS:
            console.log("News are ",action.items);
            return action.items;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Second Reducer File:

```js
import news from './news_reducer';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    news
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Then I am importing my rootReducer from reducer folder in index.js outside of source folder where my redux store is.
This is how I am creating my store in index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Now, My problem is that I am trying to send data from actions but reducer isn't recieving it for some reason.

Another Error popped up now. [Another Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9uO3.png)

Comment: What is the default value for the `news` attribute on the `state`?

Comment: Check the state value. What is it? Maybe adding prop-types would be helpful so you can see when the array is not present.

Comment: post the reducer and how you populate news array

Comment: @Karim just edited

Comment: It should be `news: action.payload` not `news: action.items` in the reducer

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Thanks for pointing that out. I am at the point where I can't see the mistakes I am making.

Comment: @mhamzah1993 No problem :) Typos are common source of a head ache if the language is not staticly typed.

Comment: My problem still persists. I have tried many different solutions from stack overflow but none of them work for me.

Comment: How is your store configured? Is your reducer properly configured in your store? Maybe the actions are working fine, but the reducer isn't called correctly because it is not included in the combine reducers.

Comment: @ageoff Hey, I have changed my reducer file upon your suggestion and now I am getting a different error than before. I have put them in the question above.